# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I'm trying to check for NULL

Tags: c++, xcode, memory, null, sdl-2

I'm trying to implement a simple Color Keying engine example based on LazyFoo's awesome tutorials (http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/10_color_keying/index.php) but when I try to run it, the thread gives me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0) on a pointer despite the fact that I'm trying to test whether that pointer is null or not. Here's what the class looks like:

```
//Texture wrapper class
class LTexture
{
public:
    //Initializes variables
    LTexture();
    //Deallocates memory
    ~LTexture();
    //Loads image at specified path
    bool loadFromFile(std::string path);
    //Deallocates texture
    void free();
    //Renders a texture at a given point
    void render(int x, int y);
    //Gets an image's dimensions
    int getWidth();
    int getHeight();
private:
    //The actual hardware texture
    SDL_Texture* mTexture = NULL;
    //Image dimensions
    int mWidth;
    int mHeight;
};
```

and here's the intialize and destroy methods:

```
LTexture::LTexture()
{
    //Initialize
    mTexture = NULL;
    mWidth = 0;
    mHeight = 0;
    printf("I initialized");
}

LTexture::~LTexture()
{
    free();
}
```

And my error lies in the `LTexture::free` method.

```
void LTexture::free()
{
    //Free texture if it exists
    if (mTexture != NULL) //HERE IS THE ISSUE. WHAT IS WRONG WITH THIS?
    {
        SDL_DestroyTexture(mTexture);
        mTexture = NULL;
        mWidth = 0;
        mHeight = 0;
    }
}
```

As you can see in-line, the issue appears when I test if mTexture is NULL, which I believe should be valid, but for some reason it's not. What am I doing wrong? Will posting more of the code help?

Comment: Yes, it would. You are probably copying the texture around, but your code does not handle this properly.

Comment: I don't understand... where would I be copying around the texture? I thought that the free() wouldn't care if the texture was copied or not?

Comment: That's not what he meant. 1. Put `LTexture(const LTexture&) = delete;` in your class definition. 2. Compile and you will shortly see the places you're copying instances of your object class (because they can no longer do so). See [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) for more information.

Comment: So do I need to write a Copy Constructor for the class?

Comment: Not necessarily. You only have to delete the standard copy constructor as it is wrong in this case.

Comment: What would that look like? Where do I put that in? (Sorry, I'm still a bit of a n00b with C++)

Comment: I edited my answer and it contains just that.

Comment: Thanks! But also, ooooops... I just found my error... I had set my objects as POINTERS, rather than actual objects themselves.

Comment: How did you manage to get the destructor called automatically on a pointer?

Comment: I changed the objects back to objects and it fixed itself

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably that you do not handle copying and moving correctly.

Whenever you copy the `LTexture`, only the pointer gets copied. If the copy then goes out of scope, the destructor is called. Then, the original goes out of scope at some point and the destructor is called again on the same pointer leading to double freeing.

I would recommend using a smart pointer:

```
#include <memory>
class TextureDeleter { void operator()(SDL_Texture* t) { SDL_DestroyTexture(t); };

// in the class
std::unique_ptr<SDL_Texture, TextureDeleter> mTexture;
```

You can then delete your destructor.

*Edit*: If you **really** don't want to use `<memory>`, then you can achieve the same kind of safety by just adding

```
LTexture(const LTexture &) = delete;
LTexture& operator=(const LTexture &) = delete;
LTexture(LTexture &&) = delete;
LTexture& operator=(LTexture &&) = delete;
```

to your class.

But, as pointed out in the comments, this only works if you don't actually need to move or copy your class. If you do, you have to use `shared_ptr` which is nontrivial to create yourself.

Comment: Note: If the member is a `std::unique_ptr`, copying won't be allowed without custom copy-ctor provisioning. If multiple instance need to *share* the same SDL_Texture, a shared pointer may be appropriate.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this without `#include`ing another header? Like, using the stuff I've already written? I'm trying not to stray too far from LazyFoo's original examples...